# Querying Multiple Joins for Laravel Nova Lens

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-nova

I am trying to figure out how to create a query for a Laravel Nova Lens. I know the underlying query is effectively what is important here, but I can't figure that out either. I am trying to retrieve values from a relationship, here are my tables:

```
accounts
statements
statement_versions
```

What I want to do is retrieve a value from the `statement_versions` table, and associate it with an account in the lens. So, I want to retrieve the `balance` from my `statement_versions`, and associate it with an account. Here are how my relationships are defined:

```
// Accounts

public function statements()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Statement::class);
}

public function statementVersions()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(StatementVersion::class, Statement::class);
}

// Statements

public function accounts()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Account::class);
}

public function statementVersions()
{
    return $this->hasMany(StatementVersion::class);
}

// StatementVersion

public function accounts()
{
    return $this->belongsToThrough(Account::class, Statement::class);
}

public function statements()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Statement::class);
}
```

Here is the lens I have attempted to create:

```
public static function query(LensRequest $request, $query)
{
    return $request->withOrdering($request->withFilters(
        $query->select([
                    'statement_version.balance',
                ])
                ->join('statements', 'statement.id', '=', 'statement_version.statement_id')
                ->join('accounts', 'accounts.id', '=', 'statement.account_id')
                ->orderBy('balance', 'desc')
                ->groupBy('accounts.id', 'accounts.name')
    ));
}
```

This returns an error `1066 Not unique table/alias: 'accounts'`. How would I make this query and this lens work?

Comment: Did you get this fixed? The error message is what appears when you JOIN the same table twice without creating an alias - or something of sort -which doesn't appear to be the problem here. @hoolakoola

Comment: @hoolakoola Under which nova resource you are attaching this lens?

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is you are accessing this `lens` from `Account` nova resource.

Add following `$query->getQuery()->toSql()` in the first line of lens `query` function. It will print `select * from accounts` if you are accessing from `Account` nova resource. URL will looks like `nova/resources/accounts/lens/[lens-name]`.

It will print `select * from statements` if you are accessing from `Statement` nova resource. URL will looks like `nova/resources/statements/lens/[lens-name]`.

So depends on where you are adding the lens, modify the join statement. The current query will work If you are adding the lens under `StatementVersion` nova resource.

Hope its clear.